# Using VBA to add automation to a line in a text field shape

Tags: vba, text, automation, powerpoint

I understand VBA in EXCEL very well, but PowerPoint is something else.  So far I have generated my slides from a text file.  The title is really a question and the box below is four possible answers. I use this code to build the possible answers.

```vb
Sld.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange = line1 & vbNewLine & _
    line2 & vbNewLine & _
    line3 & vbNewLine & _
    line4 & vbNewLine
```

For each question I know which LineX is the correct answer.  When, in the slide show, I click for the next slide, I want the correct answer to change to Red and then spin one time. The next click takes me to the next slide I can manually highlight the correct answer and then add to two automation events,change fort color and spin clockwise one time in .5 seconds. But how to do that with VBA?

First select the correct line in shape 2, and then added the automation.  Point me to somewhere or share some code.  I have a lot of slides over 600 so manual is not a real option.

Thanks.

Comment: Your current methods have no means of a user to indicate which line is correct. Search on _powerpoint VBA activeX checkbox user input_ to let users check a box. Search on _powerpoint VBA edit text activeX checkbox_ to find out how to programmatically edit the checkbox text with your questions. You won't be able to animation a checkbox, but you could animate a shape sitting behind it. To do that, search on _powerpoint VBA add animation to shape_

Comment: This is for a presentation, not for the user to "select" the correct answer. The idea is to present the question with 4 possible answers. have a discussion and then with automation reveal the correct answer.  Then the next slide will be why this is the correct answer.  Then on to the next question.

Comment: Why bother with VBA? Just animate the correct answer.

Comment: First the PowerPoint slides are created from two different "text" files, one in Word and the other is just a plain text file.  There are over 650 question, and each one would have to have the automation added manually, that is many hours of work.   This is the first of three presentations so the total manual automation would be overwhelming. Since I am using VBA to create the slides it seemed natural to use it to perform adding the automation to reveal to correct answer.

Comment: To get a quicker answer, include all your background information in your original question. If you Excel file includes a cell that indicates which answer is correct, you can use that as a flag to add an animation to the correct answer automatically. That said, putting all the answers in the same shape separated by returns makes your task somewhat more complicated, since PowerPoint animations in such a setup default to animating each line line by line. Any way you can place the answer in separate shapes?